Object location in render determined by offset to it's origin point
I am only able to successfully translate a change in location in the viewport to the render, either by moving the object in edit mode, thereby not affecting it's origin point, or by resetting it's origin point to world origin.
The render is interpreting the object's origin point as the world origin, so when setting the origin point to geometry it is locked to the world origin.
This happens both in EEVEE and in Cycles. I am using Blender 4.1.1 on Windows 11 23H2.

Is there an animation keyframe which resets the location of the object? When you move it in the viewport and do nothing else, it will stay in the new position without re-evaluating the keyframe. However when you render it will always use the keyframed position. Other possible option: do you have any modifier on the object which is disabled in viewport but enabled for render? It would really help if you would at least show a screenshot of what you have there or even better, upload your file to https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.

Yes! The object seemed to have an animation keyframe. I just cleared all animation data and it solved the issue.
